# Detect when I scroll my UIWebView at top of the page

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scroll

I would like to add an URL/google bar on top of my webview, and access it by scrolling up my web page exactly as Safari do.
To do this, I would detect when the user is scrolling the page, and more over when the scroll reaches the top.

But I really don't know how.

An idea ? Thanx a lot.

Martin

Comment: What's a scrool? Sounds dangerous. :)

Comment: I've been digging around everywhere for this too, but haven't come across a decent answer yet.  Have you found anything about this Martin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also digging for the same and found a solution. I coded the following method to detect the scrolling coordinates. See below:

```
-(void)userDidScrollWebView:(id)scrollPoint{
    // NSLog(@"scrolled:::");

    NSString *x1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"scrollX"];


    NSString *y1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"scrollY"];


    NSLog(@"scroll x=%@ y=%@", x1,y1);      

    if ([y1 isEqualToString: @"0"]) {
        NSLog(@"RELAOD ME");
    }   
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: One year after, I succeded to log again ! It funny cause I used the same solution you preconize :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you want to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate for your UIWebView.

Comment: But UIWebView does not implement the UIScrollViewDelegate !
There are already some discutions about, and they say that it's only possible with javascript... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604795/scrolloffset-in-uiwebview)

Comment: Just a slight terminology nitpick: UIWebView *implements* UIScrollViewDelegate (it declares conformity to that protocol, after all). What you meant is that it doesn't *have* a UIScrollViewDelegate (and the appropriate setDelegate/delegate methods with which you could provide one -- which makes sense, because it is not a UIScrollView).

Comment: A quick check with [someWebView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIScrollViewDelegate)] shows that for all intents and purposes UIWebView is a UIScrollView.  You have to write the methods to override the default behavior.

Comment: Maybe David means you can subclass UIWebView and override UIScrollViewDelegate methods. It's a good way. Many developers get so used to delegation that they forget about subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods to solve your problem.

### For getting the pageOffset:

int pageYOffset = [[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];

### For getting the total scroll height of a webpage:

int scrollHeight = [[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] intValue];

### For scrolling the webpage to a particular offset:

[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollTop = %d",scrollHeight ]];