# Put Swipe Gesture over UIWebView to Get Scroll Direction in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, uiwebview, swipe

I want to get the scroll direction in webView. I read the code about getting scroll direction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163275/detect-when-i-scroll-my-uiwebview-at-top-of-the-page).

```
-(void)userDidScrollWebView:(id)scrollPoint{
    // NSLog(@"scrolled:::");

    NSString *x1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"scrollX"];


    NSString *y1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"scrollY"];


    NSLog(@"scroll x=%@ y=%@", x1,y1);      

    if ([y1 isEqualToString: @"0"]) {
        NSLog(@"RELAOD ME");
    }   
}
```

I have 2 Questions :-

1. About this code,I don't know where to call `userDidScrollWebView` method in my code so that I get regular updates about scrolling.
2. Another approach, I thought may be I could place Swipe Gesture over Web View but that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I implemented swipe gesture in UIWebView.

1. Add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` protocol to `ViewController.h`
2. In `ViewDidLoad` Method add the following code:

   `UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeGestureDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown)];
       swipeGestureDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
       swipeGestureDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
       swipeGestureDown.delegate = self;
       [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureDown];`
3. Add Delegate method in `ViewController.m` :

   `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
   {
       return YES;
   }`
4. `-(void)swipeDown
   {
      NSLog(@"swipe down in webView");
   }`

Similarly you can add another gesture for swipe Up.