# How to refresh a UIWebView by a "pull down and release" gesture?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scroll, pull-to-refresh

I know that this is possible in the Tweetie for iPhone or the xkcd iPhone app, but they are using a table. Any idea if this can be done for a simple `UIWebView` as well? I'm aware of the Javascript suggestions in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604795/scrolloffset-in-uiwebview), but what about making that natively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, iOS 5 has officially introduced the property *scrollView* in UIWebView. I tested it. It worked perfectly with EGO's pull and refresh code. So the problem is no longer a problem for any iOS 5 devices.

For downward compatibility, you still need @CedricSoubrie's code though.

Answer (score 13):

To retrieve scroll events on UIWebView I personnaly use this code to get the scrollview that is inside the UIWebView :

```
- (void) addScrollViewListener
{
    UIScrollView* currentScrollView;
    for (UIView* subView in self.myWebView.subviews) {
         if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            currentScrollView = (UIScrollView*)subView;
            currentScrollView.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

It's working. You can also use it to call `[(UIScrollView*)subView setContentOffset:offSet animated:YES];` The only problem may be not to pass Apple code checking. I don't know yet since I'm still in coding phase.

Anyone tried that yet ?

Comment: I know from a certain developer that she has passed the approval process whilst having something like this in the code, for removing the `UIWebView` shadows (you'd have to get the `UIScrollView` for that as well)

Comment: Works like charm! (Though I didn't submit my app to App Store yet)

Comment: Beware, this code doesn't work in iOS 5 because the scrollView of the webView class changed. Use this code instead :  if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
I changed my original post so the code is compatible with iOS 5

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference for the UIScrollView in UIWebView, simply search it by iterating trough subviews.

```
for(id eachSubview in [webView subviews]){
        if ([eachSubview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
            scrollView = eachSubview;
            break;
        }
}
```

After that you can easily wire up things to your EGORefreshTableHeaderView interface with the UIWebView and the UIScrollView delegate callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

To tell the truth, UIWebVIew class has an undocumented getter method called _scrollView;
So the code goes:

`scrollView = [webView _scrollView];`

Comment: Doing things this way is using a "private API".  If you use CedricSoubrie's method above, you are using only public methods.