# How to use a pull to refresh in a WebView ( iOS 5 )?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

How can I make a "Pull to refresh" in iOS 5 for an UIWebView ? I can't find a tutorial.

I have got a WebView in a Tab Bar application, and I want to refresh the WebView with a "Pull to refresh" like Twitter.

Where can I find a complete tutorial ?

Thank you

Comment: 'pull to refresh' really doesn't make sense for a UIWebView, seeing as   bounce scrolling upwards is so common, it would really get annoying after a while.

Comment: Maybe you can try searching Google or SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223627/how-to-refresh-a-uiwebview-by-a-pull-down-and-release-gesture

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII it quite does, see my comment...

Comment: I used this but it doesn't show the Pull to refresh :s

Comment: @H2CO3 I Know it's possible, but what I was questioning was is it HIG-compliant? And it may be possible that there is a better solution using JavaScript.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII are you kidding me? JavaScript for graphics when you can have damn fast native code?

Comment: @H2CO3 the OP said he couldn't get the link you provided to work, so I provided a possible alternate solution. I'm not saying that JavaScript would have better performance, but if he can't use a native solution (for whatever reason) that is the next-best thing.

Comment: If I want to use Obj. C., how can I do it ? Thx

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that's definitely true, but in first place he should try to get the native solution work -- if the exact same thing works for somebody else, then the error is at OP...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a tutorial, maybe I'll write one but I think it was quite simple, 
I did this slightly modifying SPPullView.

[Here you can grab the files (SPPullView.m and SPPullView.h).](http://herotyc.untergrund.net/upload/SPPullView.zip)

Relevant code in the main UIViewController is something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pullView = [[SPPullView alloc] initWithScrollView:self.webView.scrollView];
    [self.pullView setDelegate:self];
    [self.webView.scrollView addSubview:self.pullView];    
    [self.webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];
    for (UIView *subview in [self.webView.scrollView subviews] ) {
       subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // used to disable copy/paste, etc inside the webview
    }
    //[self doYourStuff];
}

//Called when the user pulls to refresh (this is when you should update your data)
- (void) pullViewShouldRefresh: (SPPullView *) view {
    [self updateYourStuff];
}
```

You can also add some logic or properties to prevent the user zooming, or deactivate the pull view temporarily while zooming.

Answer (score 0):

This works very well: http://blog.gomiso.com/2012/03/22/yet-another-pull-to-refresh-library/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and it is working fine. This may help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *fullURL = URL you want to hit;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   webView.delegate = (id)self;
   [webView loadRequest:requestObject];

   UIRefreshControl *refreshControlOnPull = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
   [refreshControlOnPull addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   [webView.scrollView refreshControlOnPull]; //<- this is point to use. Add "scrollView" property.
}

-(void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
   // Reload my data
   NSString *fullURL = The Url you want to hit;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [webView loadRequest:requestObject];
   [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```