# How to set content offset and content size in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have had to change a `UIScrollView` into a `UIWebView` due to formatting reasons.

There is a problem though that I need to be able to get the content offset back to `0, 0` (as I am using reusable `UIWebView`s and changing content) and get the content size so I can place a button at the bottom; but `UIWebView` does not seem to have this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way I found to sort the problem was:

1. Create a `UIWebView`
2. Put it in a `UIScrollView`
3. Add the HTML into it using "loadHTMLString"
4. Using the "- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {" delegate method I detect the size of the `UIWebView`
5. Set the frame of the `UIWebView` to the content size.
6. Remove interaction from the `UIWebView`
7. Set the Content size of the `UIScrollView` to the content size.

Then used the functionality of the `UIScrollView` instead of the `UIWebView`.

Thanks
-JM

Comment: what you doing in the 5th and 7th steps? Maybe, some code example? Whhich content size?

Comment: I think that this is a really bad idea since you'll end up creating a UIWebView that will exhaust all your resources - creating a UIWebView that is thousands of pixels high is bad news.

Answer (score 28):

This problem can be solved quite easily:

```
[[webView scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 44, 0)];
```

Remember that UIEdgeInset is different from CGRect! 
A guide on UIEdgeInset can be found [in the iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 7):

Use JavaScript.

I think that the next line should do the magic:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scroll(0,0)"];
```

Comment: Ill give that a try. What about getting content height so i can add a button at the bottom of the UIWebView?

Comment: Hmmm. This one is more complicated. I believe it is possible. I suppose that you have to take in account the height of the webView, the height of the HTML (by using JavaScript) and the current zoom level. Or, you might disable the zoom (if not done so yet) and then it will be much simpler. Just locate your button so that its bottom will be few pixels above the height of the webView. you should locate it above the HTML by using style/CSS (google for "css floating div").

Comment: By the way, you might locate an Objective-C button (UIButton) above the web view. This way you you won't need to learn CSS or JavaScript at all...

Comment: See the solution I did above. Seems to be working just got a few tweaks and then should be fine... :o) Cheers for your help.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem and definitely using javascript script is the best option you have!

Answer (score 3):

Now you can ask for the `contentSize` property of the `scrollView` property of a `UIWebView`. 
This enables you to also change the content size of that web view, using `CGSizeMake (width, height)`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the `UIScrollView` that is inside the `UIWebView`, it will be easy to change ContentOffset and `contentSize`. Information here on how to get the scrollView : [ScrollOffset in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604795/scrolloffset-in-uiwebview/4086352#4086352)