# How to prevent UIWebView scroll to top when I load a new html string?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a html string, and I load the html string to UIWebView, and the user may scroll down the UIWebView . When sometime the html string I changed ,so I call the UIWebView load the new html string. But when I load it ,the UIWebView scroll to top.The difference between the new string and the old string may be little ,so I don't what the UIWebView scroll to top. It should be the previous position  what the user scrolled it. How can I do that ?

Comment: the content of the uiwebview changed and reloaded.. one of solutions that i see is to check the previous offset of the uiwebview and store it..when the new html string is loaded scroll your web view to the same offset..if you can the difference between the two html contents try to add it to the old offset.

Comment: I search a lot of problems about setting contentoffset, it did not seem to work...

Comment: try this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525256/how-to-set-content-offset-and-content-size-in-a-uiwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the content of the uiwebview changed and reloaded.. one of solutions that i see is to check the previous offset of the uiwebview and store it..when the new html string is loaded scroll your web view to the same offset.
if you can get the difference between the two html contents try to add it to the old offset.

you can use javascript to get the offset :

```
int scrollPosition = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
```

and also to scroll to the new offset using :

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scroll(0,newOffset)"];
```

Comment: I use [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scroll(0,newOffset)"]; to set the contentoffset .and then I print out the newoffset. it is correct. But the uiwebview was show in the top? It did not scroll...

Comment: try to make it for the the first webview's content..for me i have tested and it works fine.

Comment: You did't use the scroll position. This is what you should use insted of the second line of code: [_contentWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scroll(0,%d)" , scrollPosition]];